# Wrong output of Hash#keys method

Tags: ruby

Under certain conditions `Hash#keys` does not work correctly in Ruby before version 2.4

Demo code:

```
h = { a: 1, b: 2, c: 3 }
h.each do |k, v|
    h.delete(:a)
    p h
    p h.keys
    break
end
```

Ruby 2.3.8 output:

```
{:b=>2, :c=>3}
[:b]
```

Ruby 2.5.1 output:

```
{:b=>2, :c=>3}
[:b, :c]
```

I agree it is not good to modify hash when iterating. But I did not see the relation between the modification the hash and the work keys method.

Why is this happening?

Comment: Same for `values`. Fun fact: the "bug" only affects versions 2.1-2.4. Ruby 2.0, 1.9 and even 1.8 show the (correct) 2.5 behavior.

Comment: Ruby's `Hash` class relies heavily on an internal hash table implementation. I didn't check but the bug could be a byproduct of optimizations to that internal structure. Ruby 2.4 came with a new implementation using so called "open addressing". Maybe that fixed it unintentionally.

Comment: @Stefan: Yes. The bug has been fixed in this [commit](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/commit/75775157ea68efdd0b71345a37a6930e5bf1d2ef).

Answer (score 7):

Interesting question. This isn't an answer yet, but it's too long for a comment and it could help others answer the question.

## Which Rubies are affected?

I created a GitHub [repository](https://github.com/EricDuminil/hash_keys_bug) with a very simple spec:

```
describe Hash do
  it "should always know which keys are left" do
    h = { a: 1, b: 2, c: 3 }
    h.each do |k, v|
      h.delete :a
      expect(h.keys).to eq [:b, :c]
    end
  end
end
```

[image]
Thanks to [Travis](https://travis-ci.com/EricDuminil/hash_keys_bug), it's easy to see which Ruby versions have this bug:

- Ruby 2.1
- Ruby 2.2
- Ruby 2.3

## When did the bug appear?

- The bug wasn't in [ruby-2.1.0-preview2](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/tree/v2_1_0_preview2)
- The bug was in [ruby-2.1.0-rc1](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/tree/v2_1_0_rc1)

## When was the bug fixed?

- https://github.com/ruby/ruby/tree/v2_4_0_preview2 was the last tag with this bug.
- https://github.com/ruby/ruby/tree/v2_4_0_preview3 is the first tag without this bug.

I just spent an hour using `git bisect` and `make install` in order to find that the bug has been fixed in this [commit (75775157)](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/commit/75775157ea68efdd0b71345a37a6930e5bf1d2ef).

> Introduce table improvement by Vladimir Makarov
>   .
>
> [Feature #12142]    See header of st.c for improvment details.
>
> You can see all of code history here:
>     https://github.com/vnmakarov/ruby/tree/hash_tables_with_open_addressing
>
> This improvement is discussed at
>     https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/12142   with many people,
>   especially with Yura Sokolov.
>
> - st.c: improve st_table.
> - include/ruby/st.h: ditto.
> - internal.h, numeric.c, hash.c (rb_dbl_long_hash): extract a
>     function.
> - ext/-test-/st/foreach/foreach.c: catch up this change.
>
> git-svn-id: svn+ssh://ci.ruby-lang.org/ruby/trunk@56650
>   b2dd03c8-39d4-4d8f-98ff-823fe69b080e

It has been confirmed by @Vovan, who found this commit 1 minute before I did.

Comment: Stefan says it reproduces on ruby 2.1 too. I don't have it locally, so can't verify.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev: Probably. My first goal was to "bisect" Ruby versions in order to see exactly when this bug was fixed. I'm launching Travis again with fewer versions to confirm Stefan's comment. I see no reason to doubt him.

Comment: I didn't try every release either. I just tested the first and last stable version of each minor (2.1.0, 2.1.10, 2.2.0 etc), then went back to a random 2.0 build (2.0.0-p648) then 1.9.3-p551 and finally 1.8.7 just for fun. Unfortunately, I couldn't find anything in the release notes for 2.1 (first version with that bug I think) or 2.4 (first version without it) which would explain the change.

Comment: @Stefan: It's been a long time I took a look at `hash.c`. Could this commit have anything to do with the bug : [d51aea54d8c](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/commit/d51aea54d8c)? It's between 2_4_0_preview2 and 2_4_0_preview3.

Comment: Where's the TL;DR for `hash.c`? ;-) I really don't know if this is a bug in `hash.c` or something deeper down in `st.c` ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: @EricDuminil it is the awesome investigation. I try to build from some commits and  found [7577515](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/commit/75775157ea68efdd0b71345a37a6930e5bf1d2ef)

Comment: @vovan: Ahahah. I just spent 1 hour with `git bisect` and `make install` and wanted to post a link to `75775157`. Let's say it was for validation purposes.